# Get everything before the second given character using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings like

```
[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf
[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf
[ABC].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf
[ABC].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf
[AB1].[XX3].sdfnwoaenwaf
[AB2].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf
```

How can I get everything before the second dot? e.g. `[ABC].[XXX]` for the first one.

Comment: didnt get ur question, u want to remove the characters 'sdfnwoaenwaf'?

Comment: Hi @NewtonSheikh, I just need to get a new list with only [ABC].[XXX].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex or use the `LastIndexOf` method of the String class or the `Split` method of the String class.

*Regex*

```
var toMatch = "[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf";

var pattern = new Regex("(.*?\\..*?)(:?\\.)");

var beforeSecondDot = pattern.Match(toMatch);

var stringBeforeSecondDot = beforeSecondDot.Groups[1].Value;
```

*String.LastIndexOf*

```
var toMatch = "[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf";

var indexOfLastDot = toMatch.LastIndexOf('.');

var beforeSecondDot = toMatch.Substring(0, indexOfLastDot);
```

*String.Split*

```
var toMatch = "[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf";

var parts = toMatch.Split('.');

var beforeSecondDot = String.Join(".", parts.Take(2));
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Your answer gives me more than I expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

`(.*)\.` is the regex you need. You may test on http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = "[AB2].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf";

Regex regex = new Regex("([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\.");
Match match = regex.Match(x);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
[AB2].[XX1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> finalStrings = new List<string>();
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf");
strings.Add("[ABC].[XXX].sdfnwoaenwaf");
strings.Add("[ABC].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf");
strings.Add("[ABC].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf");
strings.Add("[ABC].[XX3].sdfnwoaenwaf");
strings.Add("[ABC].[XX1].sdfnwoaenwaf");

foreach (var item in strings)
{
     Regex rex = new Regex("(.*)\\.");
     string[] y = rex.Split(item);
     finalStrings.Add(y[1]);
}
```